# How can I compare a string to a date when performing an aggregation query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, isodate

I have a collection called biosignals in my MongoDB, and I want to perform the following query:

```
db.biosignals.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "name": "step",
                "start_date_time": {
                    $gte: start
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "step_count": 1,
                date: {
                    $substr: [ "$start_date_time", 0, 10]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$date",
                total: { $sum: "$step_count" }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                _id: 1
            }
        }
    ])
```

So, what I am trying to do is:

- get all the entries where the 'name' field is equal to 'step' and the 'start_date_time' field is greater than or equal to the 'start' date (which is a parameter that I define in advance)
- group the results by day and get the sum of all the steps taken in each day
- and finally, sort the results in an ascending order, based on the day

The problem is that the 'start_date_time'  field is a string (that is why I apply the $substr operator in the query) whereas the 'start' parameter is a date (ISODate).

As a result, I cannot compare them using the $gte operator.

How could I make the comparison without having to go over all the data in my DB and change the 'start_date_time' format from string to date?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: pass `start` parameter as ISO string ? Mongo db honors  ISO date time string comparison.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot